# Python 3. Gtk 3. Wnck. Как скрыть окно программы после нажатия ToggleButton?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk

Есть "dock-панель" на которой отображаются открытые приложения. Если приложение вне поле видимости (за окном или свёрнуто), то при нажатии кнопки оно вызывается.

Вопрос в том, как реализовать скрытие окна?

Ссылка на код: [dock.py](http://pastebin.com/WXm2prk7)

Answer (score 1):

В Gtk любой виджет (в том числе и окно) можно скрыть с помощью метода `hide()` и соответственно чтобы показать виджет, метод `show()`.

Comment: мне надо скрыть открывшееся приложение (будь то плеер, офисное приложение и т.д.).

Comment: Тогда, может вам подойдет метод `minimize()` для объекта `Wnck.Window`?